# Add elements to a previous subplot within an active base R graphics device?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

Let's say I generate 9 groups of data in a list `data` and plot them each with a `for` loop. I could use `*apply` here too, whichever you prefer.

```
data = list()
layout(mat = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
for(i in 1:9){
  data[[i]] = rnorm(n = 100, mean = i, sd = 1)
  plot(data[[i]])
}
```

[image]

After creating all the data, I want to decide which one is best:

```
best_data = which.min(sapply(data, sd))
```

Now I want to highlight that best data on the plot to distinguish it. Is there a plotting function that lets me go back to a specified sub-plot in the active device and add an element (maybe a title)?

I know I could make a second `for` loop: `for loop 1` generates the data, then I assess which is best, then `for loop 2` creates the plots, but this seems less efficient and more verbose.

Does such a plotting function exist for base R graphics?

Comment: yeah mfg `par(mfg = c(2,1)); title(main = 'this one', col.main = 2, xpd = NA)`

Comment: rawr, I love it. Care to submit as an answer?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it expected that I can only do this once? I can't get a second title to show up. I don't need two for my situation, but now it's got me curious...

Comment: mfg determines where the _next_ _**high**_ level plot will be. if you are adding to a plot it is most likely low level and will actually be plotting where you want. so technically you need to call a high level function for it to work which also means that you cannot "move" again until you do. so you can use `plot.new()` to use it again; or use `par(mfg=..., new = TRUE); plot.new()` to get to the plot you _really_ want to use.. without new=TRUE you will probably draw on the plot _after_ the one you want

Answer (score 1):

@rawr's answer is simple and easy. But I thought I'd point out another option that allows you to select the "best" data set before you plot, in case you want more flexibility to plot the "best" data set differently from the rest.

For example:

```
# Create the data
data = lapply(1:9, function(i) rnorm(n = 100, mean = i, sd = 1))

par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
layout(mat = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))

rng = range(data)    

# Plot each data frame
lapply(1:9, function(i) {

  # Select data frame with lowest SD
  best = which.min(sapply(data, sd))

  # Highlight data frame with lowest SD by coloring points red
  plot(data[[i]], col=ifelse(best==i,"red","black"), pch=ifelse(best==i, 3, 1), ylim=rng)

})
```

[image]

Comment: eipi10, thanks for this suggestion, but this requires two `lapply()`s which I am hoping to avoid. Too verbose for my taste compared to a single line `par()` call.